# SharePoint Designer Weekly Alert Mail

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, list-view, designer-workflow, recurring-events

In below print screen I need to send weekly alert mail for items which have "NOT ORDERED". I don't have access for VS or TimerJob. I've only access for SharePoint Designer. Please provide steps or link to archive this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an ideal SharePoint timer job requirement.

Since you have once access to SPD, you can do it as follows

You can create a Site Workflow. Inside the workflow

1. Create a local variable to store NumberOfItems
2. Create a local variable CurrentCount to iterate through a while loop
3. Create a local variable to store item details (This will be used in the email body)
4. Create a while loop and iterate through the item "Not Ordered"

   - Set local variable "itemdetails"
   - Add one to the variable "currentcount"
5. After the loop add a send email activity and send email
6. Now use a Pause activity for waiting one week and then repeat the process in another loop.

Comment: Thanks Amal, As I'm first time going to create workflow it will helpful if you provide some link where I can see above steps with print screen or in more details so in case if I'll get stuck in between I can take the help with your provided link/print screen. However I've already started your provided steps and update you the status. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Amal, I've created the workflow (For testing purpose I've created workflow for 5 mints) but not getting the mails. I'm using SharePoint Online. Please find the print screen for the workflow. I've created the workflow based on the above List Print screen. Please find the print screen for the workflow which I've created.

Comment: You should send the email outside the loop. The loop is used to collect information which will be used to sent. Also confirm how you invoked the workflow

Comment: For this I've created the list in SP and then from ribbon open the SharePoint Designer 2013 -Created the workflow which I've attached -- Then Saved -- Check the error and Published. Please provide some link if you have so I can try to recreate again or do the changes which will be require.Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how well these will be handled in 2013; in 2010 and below having endless workflows like this hang around usually become unreliable.  I would look at running at least two workflow and have a tracking variable added to list items.  This way you can end one workflow while triggering the other.  This way they don't run more than a week at a time. Admittedly your options with SPD are not that great in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Jesus for your comment. I'm using Office 365 Small where I think I can't use (Not Sure) Visual Studio or Timer Job for this workflow, Do you have any idea if I can archive this task in Office 365 Small. Please advice.